# PHPDoc not passed with variables from controller to views in Yii2 and PhpStorm

Tags: yii2, phpstorm, phpdoc

Simplified code:

Model:

```php
/**
* @return array{name:string,age:int,group:int}
*/

public function fetchStudent($id){
   //fetch $id student from db and return array
   (...)
}
```

My controller:

```php
$students = $myStudentsModel->fetchStudent(123);
```

Now in the controller when I try to use code completion in `$students` variable, the **returned array structure** is automatically suggested as defined in PHPDoc.

However, when I finally pass it to a view:

```php
return $this->render('student', [
   'student' => $student
]);
```

in the view file the `$student` variable **knows nothing** about the array structure it knew when in controller.

I tried different PHPDoc tags (e.g. uses), changing array structure to `[#ArrayShape]` attribute, pulling params in the view from `$this->context` - nothing works. PhpStorm 'loses track' of a variable once passed from controller to view.

Do you have any idea how to pass docs alongside variables to views?

Comment: I usually just declare passed variables in php doc somewhere at the start of view template. For example like this `* @var array{...} $student`. To get passed variables in view templates automatically you will probably need some plugin. I don't know about any plugin that would be able to do that.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about it but the issue I see is that whenever you edit the returned array from your model method, all the places in views where you used the fetched data need to be updated as well. Editing the source signature would be less cumbersome and error prone.

Comment: @Joey you can always use some object instead of array as return value from that method. Then you won't need to update definitions in templates when its structure is changed. And using object is even safer because it can prevent states where array structure was updated but it's definition in method's doc block wasn't.

Comment: @LazyOne looks like I was expecting too much of IDE but since PhpStorm (+Yii plugin) already does know that views have parameters missing (not pushed) and raises an error in the controller the feature I was hoping to find seemed perfectly reasonable..

Comment: @Joey The IDE itself knows nothing how Yii (or any other framework for that matter) works. All framework-specific info is provided by framework-specific plugin. For example: Blade and Twig templating engines are supported by the IDE core but they do not know which type this specific variable is (or even if it is actually gets passed to the view ... as some view parameters/variables can be passed at a higher level (view composers in Laravel for example). Another case: the same view file can be called from many places .. and may get different set of variables...

Comment: @Joey The best way / what I always did with all frameworks/templating engines used till now: declare the used variables at the top of the template/view file (as long as the IDE can interpret such comments of course). Surely, knowing what vars are used without declaring them this way would be a fantastic (makes life MUCH more easier) .. but considering how the view files can be used (directly in the controller, or rendered inside another view etc) it can be hard (if not impossible) to do it properly.

Comment: @Joey And it has to be done in framework-specific plugin (as it knows how that framework actually works under the hood). Therefore it makes sense to request such  functionality in the corresponding plugins. Hopefully it can be done.

Comment: @Joey Re: return array structure. As others have mentioned -- using custom class is better than an array (as it keeps the info about internal structure). I'm not super sure, but I believe I've seen tickets on PhpStorm Issue Tracker that show that the return array structure can loose it's structure later (unless I'm confused that with similar tickets about the same for actual parameters). I believe PHPstan or Psalm have tags that define custom types/structures. Maybe that can be used (declare it in one place and use for return array and then also reference it in a view file...)? Would be good.

Comment: LazyOne yes, I thought the same - the plugin would be the most reasonable place to seek such an option. I've just been to the 'Yii2 Support' plugin author's website to see if there's any mention of the feature, silent for now alas.. Michal & LazyOne As to returning objects the problem is my model method returns an array of them. I can just decide to return an array of objects or array of arrays (each table row). Guess I'll try using one of your hints - a custom class or a declaration at the top of the view file. Thanks guys!